# How to check the same condition after each step without repeating the same code over and over in Java?

Tags: java, console

In my console application, I give the user the option to type "exit" at any point to return to the main menu. As the user enters data, i prompt him/her through the console for various things, and collect the data using `scanner`.

My question is how can I check to see if the user entered "exit" after each prompt (as opposed to the requested information) without having to use the same if statement after each step?

As I see it, any kind of `while` or `for` loops are insufficient because they only check the condition at the beginning, when I need to check the condition between inputs, and I need each input/prompt to execute only once per iteration.

The key here is that each prompt/code executed between the checks is DIFFERENT, so loops won't work.

Here is some example code:

```
String first;
String second;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


//prompt user for input
first = input.nextline();

if(first.equals("exit")){
    //return to start menu
    input.close();
    return;
}

//prompt user for DIFFERENT input
second = input.nextline()

if(second.equals("exit")){
    //return to start menu
    input.close();
    return;
}
```

Comment: I do not know what you want to create, but you can create an Array that contain the question insequence, and loop through them with a for/while loop, and in the body of the loop, have a single if statement for checking exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use an [`List<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of words. You can `return` it. Also, it's a really bad idea to close a `Scanner` wrapping `System.in`, once you do you cannot re-open it.

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; input.hasNextLine(); i++) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    words.add(line);
    if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(words);
return words;
```

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean but I'm just not sure how to implement it. For example, where would I put the prompts for the next input? they are different each time because they ask for different things. So this function that you have provided would run after each prompt? I can see it working that way. And one last question: I have been closing the scanner and just making a new one each time I need it. It has worked fine for me so far. Is there something bad about this way of doing things?

Comment: @zephos2014 What exactly are you prompts? You didn't include them, but you could certainly keep a map or a list of prompts. If you have two methods that get input with a `Scanner` around `System.in` and you close it in one, the other method will never get input.

Comment: Ah... got you this time. Well, as long I'm only using one scanner at a time that shouldn't be a problem, but I will keep that in mind. I never realized I could keep my prompts in a map. That's a brilliant idea and just might do the trick, that way I can use an array of input values in a generic loop, and still have unique prompts each time. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Write a method...

```
public boolean isExit(String value) {
    return value.equals("exit");
}
```

You can then check this method each time...

```
String value = input.nextLine();
if (!isExit(value) {
    // Handle the normal text
} else {
    // Handle the exit operations...
}
```

You could put additional code in the check, but I would prefer to have an additional method that handles the exit operation...for example...

```
String value = input.nextLine();
if (!isExit(value) {
    // Handle the normal text
} else {
    doExit();
}
```

Take a look at [Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) for more details...

**Updated**

Focus on the idea that a method should do a single job and have no side effects...

Having said that, I would setup my code in such away that if the user enters `exit` at the prompt, the method can exit of it's own accord, without the need for `return;` statement...

For example...

```
public int selectYourMeal() {
    // Prompt...
    int option = -1;
    String value = input.nextLine();
    if (!isExit(value) {
        // Handle the normal text
    } else {
        option = EXIT_OPTION;
    }
    return option;  
}
```

Where `EXIT_OPTION` is a special value, which the caller and identify and deal with as it sees fit.

I'm also old school, in that I was taught that a method should have one entry and one exit point, you really want to avoid having multiple exit points within your methods, as it becomes very difficult to follow the logic...

Comment: I think the problem with that is that I need to return from the entire method that is running. I forgot to add it at first (edited now) but the if statement has a `return;` statement to break out of the entire method. Is there another way to do that? if I put the return statement in another method it would only return out of that method, and I would have to write another if statement to check the return value of the second method anyway, so that wouldn't save me any code. Let me know if I'm wrong about something.

Comment: Okay, so a `method` should do a single job.  Here, I said, `isExit` should return `boolean` only when the `value` it is provided is equal `exit`.  You could place a `return` statement within the `else` portion of your method, but I'd prefer to simple have the logical contained within the context of the `!isExit` portion, so that no other operations occurred and the method could exit normally...

Comment: Okay, I think I'm seeing your reasoning. So in that case, each time I prompt the user I would be calling a separate method, and calling isExit method from inside those methods, correct? But then how do I avoid having the same problem on a higher level, where I need to call each prompt method in succession unless the exit option is used. I'd still be checking the condition after each step, unless I could interrupt that process somehow.

Comment: There's no "one hit solution".  You need to design your code with the concept that an "exit" can occur.  Each method would know it needs to know then an "exit" has been entered, but not that it should handle it (other then returning).  How "exit" is actually handled would the responsibility of the top level method.  Yes, you will need to check for "exit" and yes, you will need to return a state of some kind to indicate that exit occurred for the caller to know that it should stop processing and "exit" itself...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, I recommend a do-while loop. It will first take text the first time, perform an action, and if it is exit it will break the loop, otherwise it will repeat.

```
 do{
 text = input.nextLine();

 //whatever code you want here to perform with input

 }while(!(text.equals("exit"));
```

Comment: I'm going to edit my question to clarify this point, but the code that needs to run is different each time, so loops won't help. Thanks though.